# Don't store variable if not set

Tags: php, function, variables

```
function append_URL( $link, $sort ) {
  $sort = $_GET['sort'];

  if ( isset($sort) ) {
      $link = add_query_arg( 'sort', $sort, $link );
  }
  return $link;   
}
```

I get this notice `Undefined index: sort` when no `sort` parameter exists. What is the best way to check if the `sort` param exists before creating the $`sort` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sort = array_key_exists('sort', $_GET) ? $_GET['sort'] : null;
```

Also, if you're just setting the $sort value from the $_GET, why do you pass it in as an argument to your function?  It seems redundant.

Comment: Be aware that `array_key_exists()` is much slower in execution than `isset`.

Comment: @AndreKR: there is no significant difference for one call ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Nothing you and me would notice, but if his program consists only of this one call he could easily multiply his total runtime. :)

Comment: W/regards to speed - yes, it's slightly slower, but unless you're doing a hell of a lot of checks that probably doesn't matter.  There as a very simple benchmark posted in the docs, for anyone that's interested: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#82867

Comment: 100k calls. Guys, are you kidding? ;-)) On 100k you win 0.4 seconds. And now calculate how much time your whole rendering page time will be for 100k requests. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it matters - but it's good to know these things anyway, because you might one day be in a situation where it *does* matter.  Can't really imagine what that situation might be, though.

Comment: @El Yobo thanks for the answer! I use the statement to execute the function only where sort exists.

Comment: Btw, how can I use `isset` ? I get syntax error when I try to replace `array_key_exists`

Comment: First, there's not any practical difference in this case; but if you're looking in any array other than one of the superglobals, it's safer to stick with array_key_exists.  Second, you can do it like this - $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : null;

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['sort']))
```

Comment: That will fail to pick up an empty string.  array_key_exists will pick up any value, so long as the key exists.

Comment: Of course `isset` is *true* for an empty string. Maybe you are confusing it with `if ($_GET['sort'])`?

Comment: @AndreKR: he is confusing it with `$arr = array('key' => null); var_dump(isset($a['key']), array_key_exists('key', $arr));`

Comment: I stand corrected; zerkms is correct, I was thinking of the null value, where the array key exists, but the value is null.

Comment: @El Yobo: well, since all parameters from client come as strings - there is no way to get `null` there. So in this case there is no difference in behaviour of these functions.

Comment: Depends if the $_GET has been modified before it got to that function :D  That said, with my suggested approach, I would be setting null as the default value anyway, so either way it would end up the same.

Comment: I hate when people modify the superglobals. :/

Comment: Agreed that it's not normally a good idea, but it's unfortunately possible. I do have one legacy system that uses magic_quotes, so I do mess around with the globals to strip out all the goddamn slashes, but otherwise they're best left alone.

Comment: @El Yobo Of course, magic_quotes is a valid excuse... sometimes we must fight evil with evil.